# Delphi form staying on top of itself

Tags: delphi, winapi

I've got an app that has a window that stays in front of other windows, but also stays in front of other 'stay on top' windows by checking Z order and moving itself forwards if it isn't the top most. That works ok, except where my window has controls that pop things up like combo boxes and hints. Then what happens is the window moves itself in front of the hints etc.

The logic I've attempted looks at the handle of the window in front and then attempts to see if its owner (using getwindow (h,GW_OWNER)) or parent (getparent(h)) is my window. Failing that it continues to call recursively to see if my window is the parent of its parent etc.

This doesn't work and my application then tries to put itself in front of the popped-up control which is not ideal. Any suggestions on other approaches?

Thanks
Terry

Comment: These are the wages of sin

Comment: @DavidHeffernan good one. Or to elaborate: This is just one of the things you learn not to do. Choosing to make a form StayOnTop is bad enough, bad actively promoting it again and again will in deed put you in hells kitchen.

Comment: Look at them their threads, if they're from the same thread with your stay-on-top window, they shouldn't be hostile.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The wages of sin indeed, but sadly necessary because of the sins of others (two wrongs make an app?). It's behaviour that can be turned on when circumstances demand.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz An excellent point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sertac Akyuz suggested, tracking the process ID of windows and comparing that with your own ID is a way to identify window ownership.

Answer (score 0):

The hints have the application handle as parent and owner. So testing for h=application.handle solves the problem for them. Combo boxes seem to be a different story and calls to get the parent return 65556 and owner gives 0.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this reliably.

What you do is play a variation of the game of [Walls and Ladders](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22old%20new%20thing%22%20%22walls%20and%20ladders%22). Nobody can win it.

In this case you build both your wall (combobox, hints, etc) and your ladder (window wanting to be topmost). Even if you don't do that, you will not win.

See [How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).

Comment: I'm not concerned about being covered by my own windows, just other apps obscuring a small floating graphic that can invoke other windows. Something along the lines of what Sertac suggested should do it. Not terribly pretty but options are limited.